# Why bounty is given if answer not accepted?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I was searching for issue I have, and found exactly same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815818/map-of-mapfragment-gets-loaded-with-lag-when-returning-from-another-activity)

And answer is seems to be a bad practice, and what more important, not working. But bounty is given. What's the point of this?

Comment: It is half bounty for highest voted answer, if answer is not accepted

Comment: I think this answer don't deserve even half

Comment: I got your point but this is the rules as far as I know, but good point, I have also seen undeserved accepted answers

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ by this logic I can now go, and answer all bounty questions with something like "Try to reboot router, it's worked for me"

Comment: try to read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: Automatic awarding of bounties requires an answer score of 2 or above.  I doubt your "try to reboot router" answer would qualify.  You might want to read the post that maytham linked.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm pointing to answer with only 1 score

Comment: Then I guess either that post is inaccurate, or there is a bug.  Your router answer still wouldn't work... You're more likely to get downvotes, not upvotes.

Comment: @Robert that was just a bad example. Anyway, I can suggest to create static var for almost 50% of questions.

Comment: *"Bounty Ended with 25 reputation awarded by Community♦"*

Comment: @Paulie_D: That means it was auto-awarded.

Comment: A bounty is auto-awarded when it gets enough upvotes, 2 is the required minimum.  Right now the answer has only one upvote showing.  This is the kind of mishap that is pretty common with bountied questions, answers tend to attract fake votes from sock-puppet accounts.  That later get retracted again, usually because a moderator deletes the account.  A problem with this particular poster, his profile is showing 4 prior interventions.  Otherwise a good example how this kind of corruption is not innocent and produces bad Q+A.